# Bootstrap combining rows (rowspan)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-grid

I am testing [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/) and got stuck with
basic scaffolding with rows. I revisited their documentation number of times and I can see nesting columns where you can basically nest columns within a column but I cannot locate 
the capability of combining rows into one and have it aligned with column next to the uncombined rows.

Below picture should illustrate what I want to accomplish.

[image: rowspan layout sample]

The only workaround solution I came across is using tables but I don't like this idea
as my view is that the responsiveness wouldn't work with the use of tables.

Does anyone have any elegant solution to this?
Most of the web layout I do will need fine level of flexibility so it will be great if I could pick up something useful here.

Answer (score 110, accepted):

Divs stack vertically by default, so there is no need for special handling of "rows" within a column.

```css
div {
  height:50px;
}
.short-div {
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Bootstrap</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="background-color:red;">Span 5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:green">Span 2</div>
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:purple">Span 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2" style="background-color:yellow">Span 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:#999">Span 6</div>
      <div class="short-div">Span 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:#ccc">Span 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Here's [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkpjpm/DRanJ/).

Comment: Thanks very much. That's what I was looking for! I wish Bootstrap documentation mentioned this additionally under nesting columns as the approach is basically the same.

Comment: in your example you define `1row=25px`, `2row=50px`. can you make the spanned div to be as high as the entire row ?  tried adding `.row{height:100%;}` but it didn't go.

Comment: Yes, @carter the original example was not compliant with bootstrap 3; I've corrected it.

Comment: The example has gutters on the second row which looks odd.

Answer (score 101):

**You should use bootstrap column nesting.**

See [Bootstrap 3](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/#grid-nesting) or [Bootstrap 4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/#nesting):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5">Span 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3">Span 3<br />second line</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Span 2</div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Span 2</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">Span 2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">Span 6</div>
            <div class="col-md-12">Span 6</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">Span 6</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/DRanJ/125/

(In Fiddle screen, enlarge your test screen to see the result, because I'm using col-**md**-*, then responsive stacks columns)

**Note**: I am not sure that BS2 allows **columns nesting**, but in the answer of Paul Keister, the columns nesting is not used. You should use it and avoid to reinvente css while bootstrap do well.

The columns height are auto, if you add a second line (like I do in my example), column height adapt itself.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer because it works with Bootstrap out of the box and doesn't require any CSS tweaking

Comment: The accepted answer is more readable; it contains a code snippet and a link to JSfiddle and IMHO Paul Keister's examples are more  
clear than Alcalyn's examples. That's why I think that Paul Keister's should be kept as the accepted answer, at least until the Alcalyn's answer is improved.

Comment: @Alcalyn in my browser (Chrome) the linked fiddle from your answer does not produce the expected result (see picture in the question). The actual result is all divs aligned in a column.

Comment: If you see a single column with all aligned spans, this is because the `-md-` responsive rule. You must enlarge your screen to see expected result. If you need your spans to display as columns on smaller screens, replace `-md-` by `-sm-` or `-xs-`. This is a breakpoint question (See http://bootstrapdocs.com/v3.0.3/docs/css/#grid).

Answer (score 12):

Note: This was for Bootstrap 2 (relevant when the question was asked).

You can accomplish this by using `row-fluid` to make a fluid (percentage) based row inside an existing `block`.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="span5">span5</div>
   <div class="span3">span3</div>
   <div class="span2">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12">span2</div>
         <div class="span12">span2</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="span2">span2</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="span6">
      <div class="row-fluid">
         <div class="span12">span6</div>
         <div class="span12">span6</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div class="span6">span6</div>
</div>
```

Here's a [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/4GAcr/).

I did notice that there was an odd left margin that appears (or does not appear) for the spans inside of the `row-fluid` after the first one. This can be fixed with a small CSS tweak (it's the same CSS that is applied to the first child, expanded to those past the first child):

```
.row-fluid [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort but it looks like a row doesn't have to use row-fluid to accomplish this as suggested by my selected answer. I really appreciate it though!

Comment: Very true, but don't forget `row-fluid` when it comes time to start sub-splitting the inner rows.

Answer (score 7):

Check this one. hope it will help full for you.

http://jsfiddle.net/j6amM/

```
.row-fix { margin-bottom:20px;}

.row-fix > [class*="span"]{ height:100px; background:#f1f1f1;}

.row-fix .two-col{ background:none;}

.two-col > [class*="col"]{ height:40px; background:#ccc;}

.two-col > .col1{margin-bottom:20px;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Paul's answer seems to defeat the purpose of bootstrap; that of being responsive to the viewport / screen size.

By nesting rows and columns you can achieve the same result, while retaining responsiveness.

Here is an up-to-date response to this problem;

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <h1>  Responsive Nested Bootstrap </h1> 
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-5" style="background-color:red;">Span 5</div>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color:blue;">Span 3</div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:green;">Span 2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:purple;">Span 2</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" style="background-color:yellow;">Span 2</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:yellow;">Span 6</div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="container" style="background-color:green;">Span 6</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color:red;">Span 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can [view the codepen here.](https://codepen.io/d-das/pen/ZJQmzN)

Answer (score 1):

```css
div {
  height:50px;
}
.short-div {
  height:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <h1>Responsive Bootstrap</h1>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-5 col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-xs-5" style="background-color:red;">Span 5</div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3" style="background-color:blue">Span 3</div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2" style="padding:0px">
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:green">Span 2</div>
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:purple">Span 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-2" style="background-color:yellow">Span 2</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <div class="short-div" style="background-color:#999">Span 6</div>
      <div class="short-div">Span 6</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6" style="background-color:#ccc">Span 6</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is not working for me with  <div class="col-sm-2">
           <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" style="background-color:yellow;">
            <input type="file" id="imgInp" name="img" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg" > <!-- <input type="text" src="" class="form-control" id="imgName" size="40" ></input>--> 
            <img id="img-upload" src="" alt="Transporter" width="300%" height="50%" class="rounded-circle" />
           </div>
          </div>           
        </div>

Comment: Please add explanation around your code. So that OP and future reader can easily understand your answer.

Comment: I took span2 only and it's working perfectly, `<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-5" style="padding:0px">
  <div class="short-div" style="background-color:green">Span 2</div>
  <div class="short-div" style="background-color:purple">Span 2</div>          </div>
            <div class="col-sm" style="background-color:yellow">Span 2</div>
        </div>` with CSS `.short-div {height:50px;}`  Nice snippet @SUDIPSINGH