# bootstrap rowspan 2 for middle column

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to create the following table with bootstrap, need the middle column spanning 2 rows. I'm having problems. Any help? I know the code below isn't right at all.

```
<div class="row">
<div class=col-sm-2">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">2</div>
<div class=col-sm-2">3</div> 
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class=col-sm-2">4</div>
<div class=col-sm-2">5</div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap combining rows (rowspan)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I get a Bootstrap column to span multiple rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16390370/how-can-i-get-a-bootstrap-column-to-span-multiple-rows)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to look at what is happening a bit differently. You actually want to have 1 row with 3 columns

- 1st column: #1 & #4
- 2nd column: #2
- 3rd column: #3 & #5

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div> 1</div>
    <div> 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-8">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2">
    <div> 3</div>
    <div> 5</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The thing is though I want #2 above #4 so those contexts is higher than #4 for indexing purposes

Comment: You will most likely need to do something custom for this. Perhaps using flexbox or masonry.js. You obviously have to weigh whether implementing a custom solution is worth the value of indexing.