# CSS how to stack div's one on top next to a primary div

Tags: html, css

How do you accomplish the following HTML `table` using `div`'s and `css`?

```html
<table border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="2">Form Location</td>
      <td rowspan="1">Filter Location</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td rowspan="1">Data Location</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: use bootstrap's grid system or see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan

Comment: On the client site flex doesn't work and I would have to get approval to use bootstrap which seems excessive to accomplish what I am looking for. Obviously, I can make the `table` work but I think its bad form.

Comment: What was this voted down? The question was very specific. I wanted `css` method of accomplishing the task rather than using `table`s.

Comment: because looks like you did not try to learn how to do it, just came here to get your job done for someone else

Comment: @LPZadkiel that is quite the assumption. I did try to figure it out myself but since I am not an artist I have trouble with CSS. I needed a little boost; I thought that is what this forum is all about.  Nitin Dhomse did just that. I am not an HTML, CSS guy by trade.

Comment: yeah the thing is you did not post what you have tried so leave a window open to think that you havent even try. I didnt downvote but i understand the one who did it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your DOM structure table to div as follows:

```html
<div style ="width : 300px;">

  <div style = "float : right">
   
    <div>Filter Location</div>
    <div>Data Location</div>
  </div>
  <div style = "float : left">
 <div>Form Location</div>
   
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: This looks very promising.

Answer (score 0):

Piece of cake with Flexbox.

```css
div {
  padding: 2px;
  border: #00f solid 1px;
}
.main {
  display: inline-flex;
}
.main .left {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.main .right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="left"><span>Form location</span></div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="up">Filter location</div>
    <div class="down">Data location</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#container {
  display: inline-block;
}

#table {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#left {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 5px;
}

#right {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#right div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

#right div:first-child {
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}
```