# BOOTSTRAP - Is it possible to make the following layout?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make the following layout using bootstrap

my problem is that I do not know how to give div one (**1 in picture**) following height

[image]

Comment: You can find an example in here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16351404/bootstrap-combining-rows-rowspan

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example : https://codepen.io/pof/pen/abWqgjJ

and the basic layout could look like that :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        Picture 1
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 2
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 4
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 5
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 6
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 7
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 8
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 9
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 10
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 11
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 12
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                Picture 13
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But maybe I'm missing something... Can you provide your code ? Which version of bootstrap are you using ?